# Kill a suspended Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How to get all the suspended threads and kill them? I am working on a web application which starts a thread named TImer-0 which is suspended most of the times.When i terminate the apache server it shows that 
**SEVERE: The web application [/LoggingMonitor] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.**

Comment: Is it suspended with Thread.suspend? Or do you mean it's generally not doing any activity?

Comment: this is a follow up to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677008/catalina-out-memory-leak-error

Comment: Let the container manage the threads.  It will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

Comment: actually catalina is showing this problem.

Comment: i don think that there is some bug in tomcat or is it?

Comment: Daemon Thread [Timer-0] (Suspended) 
 TimerThread.mainLoop() line: not available [local variables unavailable] 
 TimerThread.run() line: not available

Comment: This is the trace.All other threads are running but this thread is suspended and causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to suspend threads, as that may stop the entire process working. Even if you do have suspended threads, stopping them is not likely to help.

`Timer-n` sounds like `java.util.Timer`. This can be cleaned up by calling `cancel`. So long as you don't have a memory leak, the thread should be collected eventually (cancelled by a `finalizer`).

Comment: i didnt suspend the thread.When i debugged the application it showed that all other threads were running but timer-o thread was suspended most of the times

Comment: i am using timer.cancel() in onContextDestroyed of servlets,is that ok?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't kill the thread, instead free the resources (memory excluded since it is freed by the gc) it uses and let the scheduler stop it . [Thread.stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) is deprecated (just as suspend). 
If you have to stop the thread manually use a flag as seen [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/stopping_thread.shtml) or [here in the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java).