# Tracking Java thread creation and lifetime

Tags: java, multithreading

Are there any tools available to track the creation and lifetime of Java threads? I would be interested in all of the following:

- The call stack which called new Thread()
- The call stack which called start()
- The lifetime of the run() method

Comment: Is subclassing an option in your particular environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written and published an open source tool to answer this question.

[Java Live Thread Analyser](http://mchr3k.github.com/jlta/)

I have blogged about the tool [here](http://mchr3k-coding.blogspot.com/2012/04/java-live-thread-analyser.html).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any framework like this.  You certainly could subclass the `Thread` class and store this information on your own like the following.  This however will not track `Thread`s that are allocated in other classes such as `Executor`s, etc..

```
  public class MyThread extends Thread {
      StackTraceElement[] constructorTrace;
      StackTraceElement[] startTrace;
      long runStartTimeMillis;
      long runFinishTimeMillis;

      // you'll need to duplicate the constructors you need
      public MyThread() {
         super();
         constructorTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStacktrace();
      }

      @Override
      public void start() {
         super.start();
         startTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStacktrace();
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
         runStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
         super.run();
         runFinishTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
  }
```

Comment: You can also use `Thread.currentThread().getStacktrace()` and `System.nanoTime()` for timing.  You can also just store the `new Throwable` and only take the StackTrace if you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Peter re: `Thread.getStacktrace()`.  I forgot about that.  The stacktrace is filled in the `Throwable` constructor so I don't think that saves anything.

Comment: The stack trace element array is not actually filled until it is called for the first time.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  `getStackTraceElement` I guess translates the native structures into Java `StackTraceElement`.  Makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VisualVM now(*) has a tab for threads

[image]

(*) Not sure since when