# How to track origin of a thread from pools?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization

I am optimizing my server app by using profiling in Netbeans and found some wild threads with default names (something like `pool-25-thread-1`) produce 40 of them when every new user login and never terminate. I am tracking the threads I started by thread pool, but those threads seems comes from third-party class and out of my control.

I have to find a way to track and find the source of those threads (which class started it) to avoid or improve those third-party codes.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874641/tracking-java-thread-creation-and-lifetime

Comment: @Sajith The agent crashed at startup, it seems cannot track class from classloader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could attach a debugger and put a breakpoint in `Thread.start()`.

Comment: when you break in the Thread.start() method, you should be able to inspect the current stack and _see_ where the threads are coming from.

Comment: The problem comes from compiled code, I don't know which one.

Comment: @Shisoft - i don't understand your question.  are you referring to native code?

Comment: @Shisoft - okay, how does that affect my suggestion?

Comment: @Shisoft - that would be something to ask your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the entry point of a thread by looking at its stack trace, and this should usually give you a reasonable idea of which library was responsible for creating it.

Comment: I have used VisualVM and tried to dump threads. But the stack trace only tells me the threads comes form a thread pool, and I still have no idea  where the pool comes from.