# How to restrict the multithreading in a Java program?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating an online judge, for this I want that the submitted java code should not utilize the parallel processing of CPU. So, I want that the multi threading of the Java application to be disabled.

The application sent to the server would be just a single java file, it would be compiled to byte code and then executed, suppose the application is using threads, it is creating a thread, the application should be closed by throwing some exception like Permission Denied like error.

Comment: Just dont use threads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread creation listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491112/thread-creation-listener)

Comment: I would be not using, some user who is using my online judge can, he may send the code which includes the threads, so I want to reject his code by throwing some exception or by introducing some error

Comment: You have to use a security manager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039987/2588800

Comment: @Tibrogargan it involves in the code, I would be executing the code simply by `java <class name with main method>,`  so I would not be adding wrapper

Comment: @SvetlinZarev it seems reasonable

Comment: You're going to need to write some code at some stage.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I think this too, I think have to invoke the class by a java application

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, You should re-post that comment as an answer.  And Nimit, You should accept the answer if Svetlin re-posts it and it works for you.

Comment: You can do bytecode manipulation at runtime (possible with [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/)) and create proxy classes to stop user from creating a native thread and throwing some exception/error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of threads, use a tread pool. Create a threadpool with desired parallelism, for example, 1:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

replace thread creation with submitting tasks to the thread pool:

```
Runnable r = ...
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
...
t.join();
```

replace with

```
Runnable r = ...
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(r);
...
future.get();
```

this way you can create as many parallel tasks as you want.

Comment: This answer does not help the OP because the OP is not the author of the code that might create threads. The OP wants to create a system to _judge_ the code (e.g., think "coding contest.") The contest rules say, "single threaded," and the OP wants an automated way to reject entries that don't obey that rule.

Comment: Yes, Its not what I wanted, I want to enforce the multithreading to only 1. I was trying to use apparmor for it, still no progress